# Applescript to click on search results/other web page buttons and links?

Tags: applescript

How would I use Applescript to click on a web link in a google search. Can I identify them by name or number or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari:

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "http://google.com/search?q=example"
    do JavaScript "window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      document.querySelectorAll('.r a')[0].click()
    })" in document 1
end tell
```

Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "http://google.com/search?q=example"
    tell active tab of window 1
        execute javascript "window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          document.querySelectorAll('.r a')[0].click()
        })"
    end tell
end tell
```

Edit: try something like this to match a YouTube result by title:

```
document.querySelector('.yt-uix-tile-link').click()
```

Edit 2: changed `window.onload=function(){}` to `window.addEventListener('load',function(){})`.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept as soon as I know which part of that would tell me what result I am clicking on, because that works for the first on the page.

Comment: Also how would I replace the '.r a' to adapt for youtube?

Comment: It highlights the period in `.yt-` and says `expected end of line, etc. but found unknown token`

Comment: Great answer; I suggest using `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ...` instead of `window.onload=function(){...`, as the latter only allows a _single_ listener to be attached, possibly conflicting with one attached by the target page. Also, since only a _single_ link is needed, using `document.querySelector()` is simpler. To put it together: `"window.addEventListener('load', function(){document.querySelector('.r a').click()});"`

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Lauri Ranta's great answer, here is **convenience function `clickOn()`**, which:

- accepts a target document, a CSS selector string plus a zero-based index to select among what the selector string matches, and **simulates a click** on the element thus identified.
- works **irrespective of whether the target document is still being loaded or has already fully loaded** - this turned out to be non-trivial. (Lauri's code relies on the `window` object's `load` event not to have fired yet).
- works with both Safari and Google Chrome (if you don't have Chrome installed, you'll have to comment out a few lines)

**Examples** that use a delay to demonstrate that the click works even after the document has fully loaded:

```applescript
# SAFARI
# Click on the *2nd* result returned from googling 'example' with Safari:
tell application "Safari"
  open location "http://google.com/search?q=example"
  delay 5 # sample delay - NOT needed
  my clickOn(document 1, ".r a", 1)
end tell

# CHROME
tell application "Google Chrome"
  open location "http://google.com/search?q=example"
  delay 5 # sample delay - NOT needed
  my clickOn(active tab of window 1, ".r a", 1)
end tell
```

---

**`clickOn` source code:**

```applescript
on clickOn(doc, cssSelector, ndx)

    # If no explicit index (into the matches returned by the CSS selector)
    # is specified, default to 0.
    if ndx is missing value or ndx = "" then set ndx to 0

    # Synthesize the JavaScript command.
    set jsCode to "
     (function () { // Use a closure to avoid polluting the global namespace.
         function doIt(t) { // Helper function
           if (doIt.done) return; // Already successfully called? Ignore.
           try {
                // Perform the desired action - may fail if invoked too early.                              
                document.querySelectorAll('" & cssSelector & "')[" & ndx & "].click();
           } catch(e) { 
                return; // Return without setting the success 'flag'.
           }
           doIt.done=true; // Set success 'flag' as a property on this function object.
      };
      // Attach a listener to the window's load event for invoking the helper function then.
      window.addEventListener('load', doIt);
      // If the document signals readiness -- which may still be too early, we can't know --
      // also try to invoke the helper function *directly*.
      if (document.readyState === 'complete') { doIt(); }
    })();
"
    # Execute the JavaScript command in the target page.
    if class of doc as text is "document" then # Safari: a «document» instance was passed
        using terms from application "Safari"
            tell doc to do JavaScript jsCode
        end using terms from
    else # Google Chrome: a «tab» instance was passed
    # !! IF CHROME IS NOT INSTALLED, SIMPLY DEACTIVATE THIS `using terms from` BLOCK.
        using terms from application "Google Chrome"
            tell doc to execute javascript jsCode
        end using terms from
    end if

end clickOn
```