# How can I reset Google Chrome via Applescript or shell on a Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

Here's what I have so far:

```
set chrome_clear_url to "chrome://settings/clearBrowserData"
set chrome_settings_url to "chrome:///settings"
tell application "Google Chrome" to quit
delay 1
tell application "Google Chrome" to launch
delay 1
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 2
tell application "Google Chrome" to open location chrome_clear_url
delay 2
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementById('clear-browser-data-commit').click();"
end tell
delay 2
tell application "Google Chrome" to open location chrome_settings_url
delay 2
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementById('reset-profile-settings').click()"
end tell
delay 2
return
```

This replies with a missing value:

```
execute active tab of window 1 javascript "document.getElementById('clear-browser-data-commit').click();"
    --> missing value
```

How can I properly load settings and reset the browser via AppleScript?  I suppose I'm open to non-Applescript solutions as well provided they're efficient.

Answer (score 3):

**Your own answer is definitely the way to go here.**

However, this answer **explains why the JavaScript interaction didn't work**; the **techniques** used here **may come in handy in other situations**.

---

The problem is not in your AppleScript code, but in your *JavaScript* code:

The problem is that the HTML source in `chrome://settings/...` pages uses `<iframes>` for the main content, so that accessing their elements directly with `document.getElementById()` does NOT work -- you'd instead have to target the *iframe* element's `document` object.

Unfortunately, since the URL of the `<iframe>` element in question, `chrome://settings-frame/settings`, has a different 'domain' from the enclosing page (`settings` vs. `settings-frame`), Chrome won't let you access the frame's separate `document` object  for security reasons (same-origin policy); in other words: `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1].contentDocument.getElementById('clear-browser-data-commit')` will NOT work.

However, you CAN simply **load the `<iframe>` URL directly**, as demonstrated in this snippet:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome"
  open location "chrome://settings-frame/clearBrowserData" # !! The *iframe* URL!
  tell active tab of window 1 to execute javascript "
    window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
      document.getElementById('clear-browser-data-commit').click(); 
    });"
end tell
```

Note the use of a listener to the `window` object's `load` event, which ensure that the `.click()` attempt is only made once the page has fully loaded - approach courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027436/45375

Answer (score 1):

This approach is much more straightforward and is confirmed to work.

```applescript
# reset Google Chrome with Applescript and Shell
tell application "Google Chrome" to quit
do shell script "rm -rf ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default"
```