# Applescript: Truncated feed URL

Tags: applescript

I'm running into errors with this simple script. It's a validator to validate RSS feed with multiple validation sites using Safari. Everything works fine as long as the feed does not contain special characters or anything after the = sign.

The script should validate the feed that was copied to the clipboard.

For example, this feed works fine: http://thefirst.libsyn.com/rss

This feed gets truncated after ?id: https://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=510298

This is only happening on the Podbase validator site.

If I could get the script to click the Validate and Go buttons, that would be amazing, but this is pretty basic…just stuck as to why the feed is getting truncated.

---

```
set feed_url to the clipboard as string

set the podbaseurl to "http://podba.se/validate/?url=" & feed_url
set the feedvalidatorurl to "http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=" & feed_url
set the castfeedurl to "http://castfeedvalidator.com/?url=" & feed_url

tell application "Safari"
    make new document
    open location podbaseurl
    open location feedvalidatorurl
    open location castfeedurl
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `https://podba.se/validate` only makes it *look* like a single `GET` request is enough, whereas clicking the Go button interactively performs many individual `GET` requests behind the scenes whose results are pieced together on the current page (and the URL is then modified to include the submitted feed URL).
In other words: even solving the (odd) truncation problem wouldn't be enough.

Therefore, your best bet is indeed to simulate an interactive submission of a feed URL, which requires filling an input box with the feed URL and pressing the submission button.

Interactive submission must be simulated for the `http://castfeedvalidator.com` site as well, where pressing the submission button is sufficient, however.
(As you report, even though inspecting the request sent by the submission button shows that a variation of your URL - which only *prepares* the feed URL for submission - can be used to instantly submit it, doing so doesn't render the results correctly (missing styles)).

The following code implements both suggestions (the simulated-interaction approach was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23021330/45375) of mine):

```applescript
# Sample value
set the clipboard to "https://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=510298"

set feed_url to the clipboard as string

# Base URL only; the feed URL will be submitted by simulated interaction below.
set the podbaseurl to "http://podba.se/validate/"
set the feedvalidatorurl to "http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=" & feed_url
set the castfeedurl to "http://castfeedvalidator.com/?url=" & feed_url


tell application "Safari"

    activate
    set newDoc to make new document
    set newWin to front window

    # Simulate interactive submission of feed_url at podbaseurl.
    set URL of newDoc to podbaseurl
    my submitUrl(newDoc, podbaseurl, feed_url)

    # The feedvalidateorurl can be opened normally.
    open location feedvalidatorurl

    # Simulate interactive submission of feed_url at castfeedurl.
    set newTab to make new tab in newWin
    set URL of newTab to castfeedurl
    my submitUrl(newTab, castfeedurl, feed_url)

end tell


on submitUrl(doc, target_url, feed_url)

    # Synthesize the JavaScript command.
    set jsCode to "
         (function () { // Use a closure to avoid polluting the global namespace.
             function doIt(t) { // Helper function
               if (doIt.done) return; // Already successfully called? Ignore.
               try {
                    // Perform the desired action - may fail if invoked too early.
                if (/^http:\\/\\/podba.se/.test('" & target_url & "')) {                   
                       document.querySelector('#url-input').value = '" & feed_url & "';
                       document.querySelector('#url-input').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
                       setTimeout(function() { document.querySelector('#go-button').click(); }, 0);
                 } else {  // http://feedvalidator.org
                     document.querySelector('.btn-subscribe').click()
                     }

            } catch(e) { 
               return; // Return without setting the success 'flag'.
              }
               doIt.done=true; // Set success 'flag' as a property on this function object.
          };
          // Attach a listener to the window's load event for invoking the helper function then.
          window.addEventListener('load', doIt);
          // If the document signals readiness -- which may still be too early, we can't know --
          // also try to invoke the helper function *directly*.
          if (document.readyState === 'complete') { doIt(); }
        })();
    "
    # Execute the JavaScript command in the target page.
    tell application "Safari"
        tell doc to do JavaScript jsCode
    end tell

end submitUrl
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. That all works really well. The only think that is odd is the castfeed validation breaks the results page after it validates and strips out all the style compared to if ajax isn't used and you just paste the feed in and press validate your feed button.

Comment: That's amazing work and in such a short. I don't know if I would ever have figured all that out.

If I can get the validated page on Cast Feed to display properly, I'd be set. Maybe it's the JavaScript?

Comment: @Ronc: Got it. I didn't pay attention to the styles. I guess the results from the Ajax call are combined with the existing page, so interactive submission must be simulated there too - please see my update.

Comment: Thank you for the revised script and the reminder to flag as resolved. I just got back in to work to test and everything works perfectly. I can't thank you enough for your help with this.

Comment: @Ronc: My pleasure; I'm glad it helped. AppleScript alone is tricky business, throwing JavaScript into the mix doesn't help. My solution certainly benefitted from work done by others before me on this site.